# How often per day can Channeled Succor be used?

Tags: feats, cleric, pathfinder-2e, spell-slots

Channeled Succor is a Cleric feat that allows you to cast one of a number of spells instead of **one** prepared Heal spell.

> You can remove conditions with divine grace. You can sacrifice one heal spell you've prepared in your extra slots from healing font to cast one of the following spells instead: remove curse, remove disease, remove paralysis, or restoration. The spell is heightened to the same level as the heal spell you sacrificed.

This is not an action and has no frequency; it can't be *activated* as such, it just happens when you want it to.
So, how often can it be done per day?

- a) **Once per day:** You can sacrifice one of your prepared heal spells, not two or three. Next day, none of your prepared heal spells are sacrificed, so you have one to go.
- b) **As many times as you have heal spells:** You can sacrifice one of your prepared heal spells, so you do. After that, what does the feat say? It says you can sacrifice one of your prepared heal spells. So you do.
- c) **Once, ever (not likely):** You can sacrifice one prepared heal spell. Next day, ask yourself: Did I already sacrifice one prepared heal spell? Yes, I did, that one time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### B) As many times as you have heal spells*

The feat itself does not impose any restriction on its use, just provides a cost and effect.

> You can sacrifice one heal spell you’ve prepared in your extra slots from healing font to cast one of the following spells instead:

For the cost of one of your **healing font** *heal* spells, you can instead cast one of the spells listed. When you're done with that casting, you could do so again for the cost of another *heal* from your Healing Font.

This is in line with (most) Feats, which are always on. If it was otherwise, it would indicate "once per day", "once per 10 minutes", "once, ever" or similar. One such example (not counting innate spells) is [Dance of Intercession](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2745) (from the Fists of the Ruby Phoenix AP if you're concerned about spoilers) which restricts its use to "up to three times per day."

---

*note that only *heal* spells from your Divine Font feature qualify, so you are still limited to using this 1+Cha times per day

Comment: Is the asterisk in the header intentional?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov it's most likely to indicate Heal spells from the Divine Font class feature, not heal spells you've prepared in your regular slots. His title is quoting the "B" option from the question, hence the persistence of sort of incorrect language (indicated by the asterisk).

Comment: Thanks, I think this makes a lot of sense. As a matter of concise language, it's a good point to make that "one spell" is already a cost, so it shouldn't be a limit at the same time.